# VBA Alert pop up for values in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA -Alert pop up in a excel column.
In the excel sheet based on certain calculation some Growth% (column H) will be calculated and if the Growth% > 20%, a alert popup would be generated asking for the Reason Code, which needs to be put in Column I.
The code is working fine for a particular cell (say `H7`) but when I'm extending it for a range (say `H7:H700`), it's not working.
Can someone please assist me regarding this.
The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("H7:H700") > 0.2 Then
        MsgBox "GR% >20%, Put the reason code"
    End If
End Sub
```

% growth      Reason Code
34%
20%
18%

The updated snapshot of the excel sheet:[image]

Now the ASM/RSM can update their forecast and automatically Growth % will be calculated in column H ...the same values will be copied in column I (as paste special) and if the Growth % > 20% , then the alert will pop up...

The code I'm using ( with kind help of  JC Guidicelli):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCell As Range, Rg As Range
On Error Resume Next
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H7:H700").Copy
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I7:I700").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Set Rg = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I7:I700"))
If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
    For Each xCell In Rg
        If xCell.Value > 0.2 Then
            xCell.Select
            MsgBox "GR% >20%, Put the reason code"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End If
```

End Sub

The issue is for the calculation of Growth% < 20% , it's working fine...but for Growth% >20%, it's throwing the pop up but getting stuck..
Could someone please assist me regarding this..

Comment: So, you have 2 columns and multiple rows and for each individual row, you need to check whether the value is > 0.2 and you need to alert the user for every row that is > 0.2. Am I understanding you correctly? ...( If you would include a sampling of the spreadsheet data in your questions, it would be much easier for people to understand what you are asking and to test possible solutions.)

Comment: Worksheet_Change doesn't trigger on a change in a calculated formula's value.

Comment: You need a little more research on worksheet_change. 1. disabling events 2. error control 3. handling target when target is more than a single cell. 4. what triggers a Worksheet_Change.

Comment: @SeanW333....Yes ...this is exactly I want to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
When you add or paste value in your selected range, the message is showing ;)
Try and let me know, it's working for me :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range, Rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rg = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("H7:H700"))
    If Not Rg Is Nothing Then
        For Each xCell In Rg
            If xCell.Value > 0.2 Then
                xCell.Select
                MsgBox "GR% >20%, Put the reason code"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ JC Guidicelli ......Thanks a lot for your detailed answer..Tried with the code mentioned...It's working when I'm running the macro at the end ...so suppose there are 5 cases where GR% >20%, 5 times the pop up is appearing...the code I'm trying is little different ...for the H7:H700 range , whenever I intend to put value in H7:H700 range and the value is >20% , it should throw  a pop up , not at the end of the filling up..as per the code the I should encounter 5 times the pop up ...each time after the occurrence...Could you please help me regarding this ...Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Look at the answer. I edited the code and let me know ;)

Comment: Great. Glad to help you

Comment: @ JC Guidicelli...Thank you for the help....is it possible with some variant of this ...? suppose in column H7:H700 range the growth % is calculated ...I'm making a paste special in column I7:I700...and whenever the values in I7:I700, it would throw the same pop up...so basically, instead of data input if it's a calculated value , can the pop up be set...was trying with (attached the snap in the problem posted)..Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H7:H700").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I7:I700").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues...but it's not working...Please let me know if it's possible ...Thanks a ton..!!